# Deserialization exception with Immutables and Hibernate vladmihalcea jsonb type

Tags: java, hibernate, jsonb, immutables-library, hibernate-types

I'm using [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) and [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) to serialize an object as `jsonb` into PostgreSQL.

My entity is mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "data", name = "event")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Event {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "payload")
    private Aggregate payload;

}
```

The `Aggregate` looks like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "aggregateType",
        defaultImpl = GenericAggregate.class,
        visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(ConcreteAggregate.class)
})
public interface Aggregate {
}
```

And my concrete type for `Aggregate`:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonTypeName("concrete-aggregate")
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableConcreteAggregate.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableConcreteAggregate.class)
public interface ConcreteAggregate extends Aggregate {
    // fields
}
```

I get the following exception when reading from the database:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.example.ConcreteAggregate not subtype of [simple type, class com.example.ConcreteAggregateBuilder$ImmutableConcreteAggregate]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructSpecializedType(TypeFactory.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:113)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperWrapper.fromString(ObjectMapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperJsonSerializer.clone(ObjectMapperJsonSerializer.java:22)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperWrapper.clone(ObjectMapperWrapper.java:73)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor$2.deepCopyNotNull(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:39)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

Make your JSON DTO (the interface `Aggregate` in this case) implement `java.io.Serializable`.

Why?

This exception happens because the Hibernate Types tries to clone the object in `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperJsonSerializer` using Jackson through `ObjectMapper` if your class does not implement `java.io.Serializable`. So it's simply a matter of making your JSON DTO implement `java.io.Serializable` and it should work.